# Using new WebView2 control and hitting older server with window.external calls... is there any way to capture those?

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control, webview2

I am working on an Office Addin that previously used a WebBrowser control and communicated back and forth with cshtml webpages by using window.external calls (e.g. window.external.myMethod()).

We have made the switch to using the new WebView2 control that was released GA this past month and have updated our current cshtml page to use the correct calls for that control (e.g. chrome.webview.hostObjects.myObject.myMethod()).

The issue that I am requesting help for is that my addin can also still connect to older servers that are still running these cshtml pages that contain the old window.external calls on them.  I am trying to figure out a way to still pass values back and forth.

I know that there is the ability to inject some javascript that would run every time a page is loaded using the WebView2 control like:

```
    await webBrowser.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync("my javascript");
```

...we are actually doing this to hook a couple of events.  We are also able to to run WebView2's ExecuteScriptAsync as well.

I'm not sure if either of these are the way to go or if there is a better way I am not thinking of.  And if I were to inject some Javascript to run, what it would even look like!

Hope you guys have some suggestions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can connect WebView2's host objects up to `window.external` using script injected via `AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync`. For instance, in our [sample app](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/tree/master/SampleApps/WebView2APISample) I opened the Scenarios|Host Objects menu item, opened the DevTools window and ran the following code:

```
window.external = await window.chrome.webview.hostObjects.sync;
window.external.sample.property; // "Example Property String Value"
```

However there are a few potential pitfalls of which to be aware:

1. The primary potential pitfall is that the WebView2 host object support is not totally compatible with mshtml's `window.external` feature. The most obvious is that by default WebView2 uses async proxies for its host objects. You can opt-in to synchronous proxies using the `sync` property on async host object proxies, which returns a promise for a synchronous proxy. But there may be other incompatibilities as well. Rather than simply assigning the sync proxy to `window.external`, a different approach would be to make your own set of JavaScript functions that wrap around the `window.chrome.webview.hostObjects` property in order to resolve any of this issues you find and assigning that wrapper to `window.external`.
2. The `window.chrome.webview.hostObjects` property delays its initialization until it is actually referenced. You may want to delay referencing it if you can, or only assigning it to `window.external` on pages you know require it.
3. There's currently [a bug with AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/539) in which the code doesn't execute cross origin in child frames.

Comment: Thank you... I was missing the ability to use sync and the promises were throwing me off on how to get this done.